# how to access from android device into remote sql lite web service

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, ksoap2

i have built small app that gets data from remote sql lite server. im using ksoap2 for the android client and netbeans 7.4 for the web service.
my app work just fine on my emulator i get data from the sql throw the ws and into my emulator. the problem is with my mobile device. the app just dont work there. the data dosent transfer from some reason.
i did a little research and I think its because of the ip. im using ip 10.0.2.2:8080 and its probably local ip and my android just cant see it. so, how can he see it?? ive put my public ip and still the device dont get sql data.

can some one please tell my how to make this app work on my mobile?

this is my android code:

```
   package com.gy.webservice3_3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources.Theme;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
//add import
//please copy and ...
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
//add import
//add import
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;


public class Main_WebService3_3_Activity extends Activity {

    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;


    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://myAndroidIt.gy.com/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/androidWS6_3/androidWS6_3?WSDL";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://myAndroidIt.gy.com/getDataFromSql";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getDataFromSql";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__web_service3_3_);
        et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);
    //  btn2.setOnClickListener(btn2Listener);  

    }

    private OnClickListener btn1Listener=new OnClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                   
            Thread netWorkThread=new Thread(){
                @Override
            public void run() {
            SoapObject requset=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
            propInfo.setName("id");
            propInfo.setValue(et1.getText().toString()+"");
            propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
            requset.addProperty(propInfo);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requset);
            envelope.dotNet=false;

            try{            
            HttpTransportSE ht=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            final SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();         
            final String str=response.toString();
            Main_WebService3_3_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {             
                @Override
                public void run() {
                String []stary=str.split(",");
                et1.setText(stary[0].toString());
                et2.setText(stary[1].toString());
                et3.setText(stary[2].toString());



                }
            });

            }catch (Exception e) {  
                Main_WebService3_3_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {             
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Main_WebService3_3_Activity.this, "wsad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
            }
            };          
            netWorkThread.start();
        }



    };
    private OnClickListener btn2Listener=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__web_service3_3_, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

thx!

Comment: You should post this on a networking forum, because this problem has anything to do with any of your tags.

Comment: why? this is a android-sql connection problem im sure that someone here that develop on local host had the same problem.

Comment: Is your phone connect the local network or it it's connected to the mobile network?